# Jenkins userContent files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins master-slave model. Each job that is being run on slaves require a certain amount of configuration files. These files must be copied from master to each slave before the build step. So far I have been able to accomplish this with the [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin). The drawback of this plugin is that it doesn't support folders, I would like to be able to put the configuration files for slave1 in the folder slave1 and so on. Now I have a huge list of files in the dropdown menu when creating a job and asked to provide configuration files.

This plugin comes with something handy: the configuration files can be edited via the web interface.

On the other hand Jenkins provides a **userContent** folder on the master accessible via **http://[jenkins-server]/userContent** that resolves my need for folders, but I haven't found a way to edit these files from the provided web interface.

I must mention that the master is a remote machine and I don't want to connect to it everytime I need to modify a file there. Is there any way to edit the files in the **userContent** folder, or to organize the files uploaded to the Config File Plugin into folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible put all the configuration into your SCM system and allow Jenkins to fetch them when needed/as they change.

Then your configuration files are managed just like your source code.  As a bonus you can add a new node easily and developers can access and use they configuration files to test their build.

Supporting evidence:

1. [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html#BuildingAFeatureWithContinuousIntegration)
2. [Andrew Binstock](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/putting-absolutely-everything-in-version/240160762)
3. [Darryl Bowler](http://blogs.collab.net/devopsci/ten-best-practices-for-continuous-integration#.Us5mPrQ1piw)

Comment: The configuration files are already in our SCM system in a 'default' form, meaning that developers still need to edit them to adjust to slave properties (boards connected, COM ports, tests to be run). That's why it would have been more convenient to just edit them 'on the fly'. I reckon you're right and everything should get through version control, and in that spirit slave-dependent conf files should be added into the SCM system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have environment specific config files you can either load all of the individual config files into into your SCM system (this becomes unmanageable if you have a lot).  Alternatively you can still store them in your SCM system and then do some combination of scripting with Jenkins parameters to update them on the fly.